# Compact markup language and library for C#?

Tags: html, c#, markdown

I have a bunch of HTML files that will be part of a downloadable content package for mobile applications. Working without any CSS styling would help reduce the file size and also converting all pages to some Markup language, with the caveat that the application would have to convert back all the Markup language to HTML pages and apply the custom formatting if needed. To do the HTML to Markup language conversion I can use Pandoc but I need a lightweight C# library (preferably available as a NuGet package) compatible with some of the Markup languages that Pandoc spits out. Also the Markup language supported would need to be the one that helps reduce file size the most (if such a thing exist).

Although it might be related to [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/35555/1485), the OP seems to want a library that allows to do some kind of low level parsing or conversion to a custom markup language.

Comment: Are you looking for *any* kind of markup language, or (as per your [tag:markdown] tag) for something related to [Markdown syntax](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) in particular?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper For some reason I totally forget about compression, and apparently the zip format allows to extract a single file. Since what I was trying to do was to use a Markup language in order to reduce space for local storage and transit of the package, all that won't be be necessary compressing the HTML files with zip, and extracting them as needed.